# How to create dynamic forms in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I need to create a django form where the user can add as many fields as he/she needs during runtime. I don't know how to implement it in Django. I haven't tried anything yet because I can't figure out how to do it. I looked on web but I got confused with so many implementations.

Comment: Your question is too broad. At least try to explain your specific use case.

Comment: Yes it is possible. You just need to create some sort of function that creates the form based on user input.

Comment: Try reading this:

 [Making a Django form class with a dynamic number of fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478432/making-a-django-form-class-with-a-dynamic-number-of-fields)

Comment: check this : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/formsets/