# Dynamic model fields in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model, for example: "food". Each one of this has some basic info: "name" "calories", etc. I would like to provide a form where the user can add extra fields. For example, if the user is adding a new "food", beside the basic info he could also add new fields, like "sugar", "vitamins", etc.

How could I add the fields to the database so that it can be retrieved/queried later?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Jacob Kaplan-Moss has an extensive writeup on dynamic form fields:
>   http://jacobian.org/writing/dynamic-form-generation/
>
> Essentially, you add more items to the form's fields member variable
>   during instantiation.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478432/making-a-django-form-class-with-a-dynamic-number-of-fields)

[Even better.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933596/django-dynamic-model-fields)

Comment: Great link! I've implemented the first solution :) Thanks!