# How I can pass a dynamic table in template to my view to save them to my database iteratively

Tags: javascript, python, django, forms, html-table

I want to pass all datas stored in the table in my template. The table is growing by user's choices. My project is about a food ordering system and what i'm trying to do is, when user adds menus to its basket, and make an order, how can i pass the values to my view to save them to my db. I know about forms but my table is not static.. I can't imagine how it will be big.

My add row func:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var sum = 0;
      $(document).on('click', '.myaddButton', function() {

        var $foodname = $(this).closest("tr")   // Finds the closest row <tr>
        .find(".nr")     // Gets a descendent with class="nr"
        .text();
        var $foodprice = $(this).closest("tr")   // Finds the closest row <tr>
        .find(".rn")     // Gets a descendent with class="nr"
        .text();
        $('#carttable').prepend("<tr class='danger' id ='myTableRow'><td>"+$foodname+"</td><td class='price'>"+$foodprice+"</td> <td> <button class='deletebutton btn btn-danger' type='button'>   <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span> </button> </td></tr>");

      });
      $(document).on('click', '.deletebutton', function() {
        $('#myTableRow').remove();
        //$('.price').each(function() {
        //  var $price = $(this);
        //console.log($price);
        //sum += parseInt($price.context.innerHTML);

        //});

        //$('#total').html(sum);
        //sum = 0;
      });
    });
    </script>
```

My Table

```
<table  border="1" class="table" id="menutable" name="menutable">
      <tr class="danger">
        <tbody>
          {%for a in list%}
           <tr class= {% DoRandom %}>
            <td><b> {{a.name}}</b> </td>
            <td class="nr">{{a.description}}</td>
            <td class="rn"><p>{{a.price}}</p></td>
            <td id="addbutton" > <button class="myaddButton btn btn-success" type="button">
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> </button> </td>
          </tr>
          {%endfor%}
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Comment: Have you tried formsets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use little bit higher technique of form processing, then you should look at question [Making a Django form class with a dynamic number of fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478432/making-a-django-form-class-with-a-dynamic-number-of-fields)...

Second "simple" solution is to add hidden input values (which will contain food_id and quantity) together with `name` and `price` (during prepend), and wrap your table in form. E.g

```
var $food_id = ... // some how get food id
var $quantity = 1; //1 for now, but you can add increase and decrease functionality
...
// in prepend text
... + "<input type='hidden' name='food-" + $food_id + "' value='" + $quantity + "' >" + ...
```

And in your template you should add `<form>` before `<table>` (and `</form>` after `</table>` tags), or use [serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) if you are using ajax.

Third solution is to use JS object as cart, and encode it to Json before form submittion.  E.g.

```
   //in your javascript global scope
   var js_food_cart = {};
   ....
   // then on click
   $food_id = ... ;// yes, again you need food id
   $quantity = 1; // or something elese
   js_food_cart[$food_id] = $quantity;
   ....
   // then somwhere in before submit, code assumes that you have form with my_cart hidden input
   $('input[name=my_cart]') = JSON.stringify(js_food_cart);
```

Then in view you should parse your json value of `my_cart` input. In template you should add form with hidden field to pass cart value.

This approach more convenient if you will implement ability to increase/decrease quantity of food.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, i resolved the issue by casting my food objects to json and post by AJAX post.